# Responding to MS Wireless Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000 presenter buttons in WPF/WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms, mouseevent

Does anyone know how to respond to the presentation buttons of the Microsoft Wireless Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000 in WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one came back to me on this one I did a bit of research and put together a blog post...

http://richardhopton.blogspot.com/2009/08/responding-to-mediapresentation-buttons.html